# SwiftUI ViewBuilder: is it guaranteed that in `if/ese` statement `else` clause isn't executed when condition is true?

Tags: ios, swiftui, viewbuilder

I ask this because I suddenly realized today that, since the `if/else` statement we use to build View in SwiftUI is interpreted by `ViewBuilder`, it may behave differently than the plain old `if/else` statement in Swift language. Could it be that, for some (e.g. performance) reason, SwiftUI pre-execute both clauses and cache the result? Does anyone know it for sure?

I remember I observed some confusing behavior in the past, which might be explained by this hypothesis. But unfortunately I can't recall an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way a result builder transforms your code is spelled out in [SE-0289: Result builders](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md). Section [“Selection statements”](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md#selection-statements) describes how `if/else` statements are transformed. It gives the following example:

> Consider the following code:
>
> ```swift
> if i == 0 {
>   "0"
> } else if i == 1 {
>   "1"
> } else {  
>   generateFibTree(i)
> }
> ```
>
> Under this pattern, the example code becomes something like the
> following:
>
> ```
> let vMerged: PartialResult
> if i == 0 {
>   var firstVar = "0"
>   var firstBlock = BuilderType.buildBlock(firstVar)
>   vMerged = BuilderType.buildEither(first: firstBlock)
> } else if i == 1 {
>   var secondVar = "1"
>   var secondBlock = BuilderType.buildBlock(secondVar)
>   vMerged = BuilderType.buildEither(second:
>         BuilderType.buildEither(first: secondBlock))
> } else {
>   var elseVar = generateFibTree(i)
>   var elseBlock = BuilderType.buildBlock(elseVar)
>   vMerged = BuilderType.buildEither(second:
>         BuilderType.buildEither(second: elseBlock))
> }
> ```

You can also read a detailed description of the transformation algorithm, but I think the example makes it clear enough that it will only execute one branch of an `if/else` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood how result builder works. A result build can only customizes the result in each branch in this case, not the `if/else` flow control.